# Python - Delete a part of each line of a textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split, strip

I have a text file like this:

```
abc123bvjhfvb:dlnvsl|smth
 fsbffsb378hbdcbs:v5v3v|smth
 sdcg87wgn8:vy5b4|smth
 sin87s88vnus:y54545v4v|smth
 rc8n782c:efghrn|smth
```

As you can see there is a space starting from the second line.

How can I convert these lines to these?

```
abc123bvjhfvb:dlnvsl
fsbffsb378hbdcbs:v5v3v
sdcg87wgn8:vy5b4
sin87s88vnus:y54545v4v
rc8n782c:efghrn
```

I tried something like this:

```
lines = open("file.txt").readlines()

for x in lines:
    x.strip(" ").split("|")
    print (x[0])
```

But it prints only the "a" of abc123 and then a series of space for each line. I think the [0] goes to print the first letter instead of printing the first part of split before the "|" (for example abc123bvjhfvb:dlnvsl)

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to assign `x.strip(" ").split("|")` to some variable.

Comment: print x.replace(" | smth","")

Comment: x[0] refers to the first character in the string x, and x is the entire line.  split() returns a result, which you're not assigning to anything.  You need to assign the result to y, then y[0] will refer to the first element in the array for that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [0] at the end of the split bit otherwise you are string indexing, not indexing the parts of the split.

You'd also be good to assign a variable fur the strip and split bit and then print it i.e. y = ... print(y)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `strip` and `split` do not mutate `x`.

The code needs to use the returned value:

```
for x in lines:
    x = x.strip(" ").split("|")
    print (x[0])
```